# String не отправляется от клиента на сервер UDP client/server

Tags: python, клиент-сервер, udp

Нужно попросить пользователя ввести слово. После ввода, например "haha" если сумма букв этого слово - четное число, то получаем string1 = "ha" и соотвественно string2 = "ha". Если не четное, то string1 = "hah" string2 = "ha".Сервер должен получить два сообщения от клиента. Первое string1 и второе string2. Алгоритм написан, но отправить не получается. Что не так я делаю? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Client side:

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5001

    server = ('127.0.0.1', 5000)

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    message = input('Please type a word ')
    while message != '':

        def splitWord(w):
            split = -((-len(w))//2)
            s1 = (w[:split])
            s2 = (w[split:])
            print(s1)
            print(s2)
            return s1, s2




        s.sendto(splitWord(message).encode('utf-8'), server)
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("Received from server: " + data)  
        message = input('-> ')
        s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Server side:

```
   import socket


    def Main():
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port = 5000


        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.bind((host, port))

        print("Server Started")
        while True:
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
            data = data.decode('utf-8')
            print("Message From:  " +str(addr))
            print("From connected user: " + data)
            data = data.upper()
            print("Sending: " + data)
            s.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), addr)
        s.close()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Main()
```

[image: output]

Comment: А где у вас вызов `splitWord` ?

Comment: Допустим я делаю s.sendto(splitWord(message).encode('utf-8'), server, и получаю error

Comment: `splitWord` ничего не возвращает...

Comment: Пробую return s1, s2   и потом s.sendto(splitWord(message).encode('utf-8'). I'm confused, что должно возвращать. Код исправлен.

Comment: Если return s1, s2 и s.sendto(splitWord(message), server) то получаю a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple', а если  s.sendto(splitWord(message).encode('utf-8'), server)'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот поправил:

```
import socket
def splitWord(w):
    split = -((-len(w))//2)
    s1 = (w[:split])
    s2 = (w[split:])
    return f'{s1}, {s2}'.encode('utf-8')

def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5001
    server = ('127.0.0.1', 5000)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    while True:
        message = input('Please type a word ')
        if message == 'STOP' or message == '':
            sock.close()
            break
        sock.sendto(splitWord(message), server)
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("Received from server: " + data)  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

**UPDATE**

К примеру имеем строку:

```
string = 'HA, HA'
```

Чтобы получить `AHAH`:

```
_str = str(string.split(', ')[0] + string.split(', ')[1])[::-1]
print('Изначальная строка: [{0}] Новая: [{1}]'.format(string, _str))
```

Результат:

```
Изначальная строка: [HA, HA] Новая: [AHAH]
```

Еще 1 вариант:

```
>>> string = 'HA, HA'
>>> string.replace(', ', '')[::-1]
'AHAH'
```

Comment: File "client.py", line 19
    return f'{s1}, {s2}'.encode('utf-8')
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Какая у вас версия Python?

Comment: У меня Python 3

Comment: @AlinaKhachatrian я предоставил код на Python 3.6.x. Для версий ниже замените `f'{s1}, {s2}'.encode('utf-8')` на `'{0}, {1}'.format(s1, s2).encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Работает со словом haha и получаю Received from server: HA, HA. Когда же слово hahah то -> hahah  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 30, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__':Main()
  File "client.py", line 23, in Main
    s.sendto(splitWord(message), server)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: Вы видимо что-то не так сделали, тот код который я вам предоставил отлично у меня работает на любых словах.

Comment: Элементарная невнимательность. В моем кода нужно было подвинуть s.close(), а вам спасибо за время и доходчивые объяснения, все просто, return ничего не возвращает и когда стало понятно, что должно возвращать s1, s2 то незнание синтаксиса  "Для версий ниже замените f'{s1}, {s2}'.encode('utf-8') на '{0}, {1}'.format(s1, s2).encode('utf-8') меня и подвело. Еще раз огромное спасибо!

Comment: Можно еще вопрос. From connected user: caulif, lower Sending: CAULIF, LOWER. Так как на сервере мне нужно получить s1 и s2, и потом concatenate их и reverse и отправить обратно. Без предоставления ответа, можете ответить - это возможно сделать с кодом который имеется на данный момент или нужно переписывать?

Comment: То есть если вы отправите серверу `HAHA` он получит `HA, HA`, и вы хотите обратно клиенту отправить уже `AHAH` ?

Comment: Да, все верно. На данный момент для меня это выглядит как одно сообщение которое никак нельзя 1) s1 + s2 2) reverse. Обязательное требование - серве ждет два UDP сообщения.

Comment: Это затруднительно так как строку такого типа будет сложно склеить и одно целое. Разве что при помощи regex. Лучше отдельно посылайте на сервер строку целиком и возвращайте её реверс.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Нашел извращённый способ :)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но не могли бы вы удалить update так как работа для универа и может посчитаться как плагиат, а попробовав применить этот способ таким образом  while True: data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024) data = data.decode('utf-8') print("Message From:  " + str(addr))print("From connected user: " + data print(str(data.split(', ')[0] + data.split(', ')[1])[::-1])print("Sending: " + data)s.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), addr) s.close(). Получаю File "server.py", line 20print(str(data.split(', ')[0] + data.split(', ')[1])[::-1])
   TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Где-то табуляцию пропустили. Update я удалять не буду, так как кому-то может это понадобится в дальнейшем. И причем тут антиплагиат? Если ваше решение совпало с другим это не значит что вы его скопировали...

Comment: Честно не знаю, учусь в Лондоне, они проверяют программами на плагиат. Получается я спросил мне подсказали, но считаю, что мной была сделана большая часть и более того учиться на Computer Science / быть программистом в наше и не пользоваться stack overflow более чем странно. Кстати все вроде работает, спасибо за ваше потраченное время и помощь, огромнейшее спасибо!